# Concatenate fails in simple example

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying the simple examples of [this page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/numpy/numpy-concatenate-arrays/)

In it it says:

```
arr=np.array([4,7,12])
arr1=np.array([5,9,15])
np.concatenate((arr,arr1))
# Must give array([ 4,  7, 12,  5,  9, 15])
np.concatenate((arr,arr1),axis=1)
#Must give 
#[[4,5],[7,9],[12,15]]
# but it gives *** numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Why is this example not working?

Comment: `arr` is 1d.  Can only concatenate on that one axis `0`

Comment: @hpaulj so the example in that page is wrong? In that case how can I get the desired result `[[4,5],[7,9],[12,15]]`?

Comment: Yes, the first example under `3` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) is what you're looking for. Note the transpose at the end, this converts `vstack`'s 2x3 result to a 3x2 array.

```python
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([4,7,12])
arr1 = np.array([5,9,15])

a = np.vstack((arr,arr1)).T
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[ 4  5]
 [ 7  9]
 [12 15]]
```

Comment: `np.stack((arr, arr1), axis=1)` also works and doesn't require a transpose.